Problem generating signature HMAC-SHA256 with base64 for CEX.IO Authentication
I've been racking my brains for a while now with this authentication.
The documentation  of CEX.IO defines the conditions below.
All REST requests must contain the following headers:

X-AGGR-KEY (The api key as a string.)
X-AGGR-TIMESTAMP (A unix timestamp (in seconds) for your request.)
X-AGGR-SIGNATURE (The base64-encoded signature (see Signing a Request).)
Content-Type (All request bodies should have content type application/json and be valid JSON)

And for Signing a Request:
The X-AGGR-SIGNATURE header is generated by creating a HMAC-SHA256 using the base64-decoded secret key on the payload.
**Payload **consist from string action + timestamp + body (where + represents string concatenation) and base64-encode the output.

The action is same as api endpoint with underscores, e.g. get_my_orders.
The timestamp value is the same as the X-AGGR-TIMESTAMP header.
The body is the request body string (in all cases this is JSON stringified request params object).

But my authentication is not going well.
Now, my code is:
api_key = '00000'
api_secret = 'aaaaa'

def get_signature(api_secret, action, timestamp, body):
    payload = action + str(timestamp) + body
    decoded_secret = base64.b64decode(api_secret)
    hmac_signature = hmac.new(decoded_secret, payload.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac_signature).decode('utf-8')
    return signature

def make_request(action, params, api_key, api_secret):
    # Define the URL
    url = f"https://trade.cex.io/api/spot/rest/{action}"

    # Generate the timestamp
    timestamp = int(time.time())

    # Convert the params dictionary to a JSON string
    body = json.dumps(params)
    
    # Generate the signature
    signature = get_signature(api_secret, action, timestamp, body)
    
    # Define the headers
    headers = {
        'X-AGGR-KEY': api_key,
        'X-AGGR-TIMESTAMP': str(timestamp),
        'X-AGGR-SIGNATURE': signature,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    # Make the POST request
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
    
    # Check the response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return {
            'status_code': response.status_code,
            'error': response.text
        }

# Example usage
action = 'get_order_book'
#action = 'get_my_current_fee'
params = { "pair": "BTC-USD" }

response = make_request(action, params, api_key, api_secret)
print(response)

My key is active. But I always receive {'status_code': 401, 'error': '{"error":"Authorization Failed"}'}
Does anyone with more experience in cryptography have any idea what I might be doing wrong?
